# What is "A device attached to the system is not functioning" error in RSA encryption?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Using RSA and want to encrypt with the public key in JAVA and using public and private keys to decrypt in c#.

Encryption works fine in java but decryption in c# has this error:
"A device attached to the system is not functioning", What does it mean?

Java encryption method:

```
static String publickey = "2rRVVVFJRbH/wAPDtnwZwu+nxU+AZ6uXxh/sW+AMCBogg7vndZsnRiHoLttYYPqOyOhfgaBOQogrIfrKL4lipK4m52SBzw/FfcM9DsKs/rYR83tBLiIAfgdnVjF27tZID+HJMFTiI30mALjr7+tfp+2lIACXA1RIKTk7S9pDmX8=";

static String Encrypt(String encodedString) {
      try {
        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publickey);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("AQAB");
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] plainBytes = new String("big kitty dancing").getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        String encryptedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherData);

        return encryptedString;
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException |
            InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | UnsupportedEncodingException err) {
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

C# decryption method:

```
   static string Decrypt()
    {
        const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
        const string CONTAINER_NAME = "Tracker";

        CspParameters cspParams;
        cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
        //string str = rsa1.ToXmlString(true);


        rsa1.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>2rRVVVFJRbH/wAPDtnwZwu+nxU+AZ6uXxh/sW+AMCBogg7vndZsnRiHoLttYYPqOyOhfgaBOQogrIfrKL4lipK4m52SBzw/FfcM9DsKs/rYR83tBLiIAfgdnVjF27tZID+HJMFTiI30mALjr7+tfp+2lIACXA1RIKTk7S9pDmX8=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>+lXMCEwIN/7+eMpBrq87kQppxu3jJBTwztGTfXNaPUTx+A6uqRwug5oHBbSpYXKNDNCBzVm/0VxB3bo4FJx+ZQ==</P><Q>yasOGaJaE9xlF9T2xRuKeG9ZxCiyjhYaYB/mbtL+SIbtkRLi/AxaU4g2Il/UxhxhSXArKxIzV28zktispPJx1Q==</Q><DP>ueRgQIEFUV+fY979a1RgrVHIPpqEI1URhOMH3Q59oiXCcOumM5njyIHmWQxRAzXnG+7xlKXi1PrnRll0L4oOKQ==</DP><DQ>dfEMNgG1HJhwpxdtmqkYuoakwQvsIRzcIAuIAJh1DoWaupWJGk8/JEstHb1d+t7uJrzrAi2KyT/HscH2diE0YQ==</DQ><InverseQ>YoYF9PF6FiC0YngVeaC/eqt/ea8wMYNN3YO1LuzWpcy2exPRj2U0ZbWMvHXMUb4ea2qmhZGx1QlK4ULAuWKpXQ==</InverseQ><D>g1WAWI4pEK9TA7CA2Yyy/2FzzNiu0uQCuE2TZYRNiomo96KQXpxwqAzZLw+VDXfJMypwDMAVZe/SqzSJnFEtZxjdxaEo3VLcZ1mnbIL0vS7D6iFeYutF9kF231165qGd3k2tgymNMMpY7oYKjS11Y6JqWDU0WE5hjS2X35iG6mE=</D></RSAKeyValue>");

        string data2Decrypt = "pt0DMKQM34rIp/aw64NBRhj8HZlp31i3Nu/9SP6o2Iwl9plu8k1TDbe04cQRkIDx/h6hsAKM0j13HdauidnEEvtm0yp9WrOMGut2XJUTUxWt5/y4bosm06tYtfw5HnlNHMMBtY22caCppwfdOJbiwp9rwEtWV9tXHU7VMenlVuw=";

        byte[] encyrptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data2Decrypt);
        //Error occured in this line
        byte[] plain = rsa1.Decrypt(encyrptedBytes, false); 
        string decryptedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain);
        return decryptedString;
    }
```

**UPDATED:**

StackTrace:

```
   at
 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
 .ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at    System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle
 pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] 
rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
  at CJSecurity.Program.Decrypt() in C:\CJSecurity\CJSecurity\Program.cs
```

Comment: Could you supply the full stack trace? It's a bit strange that you recreate `PROVIDER_RSA_FULL` as it is already defined, I had to look it up, only to find out that the constant is named identically. I presume that there is no other container named "Tracker"?

Comment: Are you using something like a smartcard hardware security module (HSM)? Your system might encounter an error during an attempt to access an HSM.

Comment: @AxelKemper No I don't

Answer (score 2):

The private key is not correct. I assume the key generation failed with some strange error. I checked your private key using openssl, and it says the n does not equal to p * q.

```
$rsa1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa1.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>2rRVVVFJRbH/wAPDtnwZwu+nxU+AZ6uXxh/sW+AMCBogg7vndZsnRiHoLttYYPqOyOhfgaBOQogrIfrKL4lipK4m52SBzw/FfcM9DsKs/rYR83tBLiIAfgdnVjF27tZID+HJMFTiI30mALjr7+tfp+2lIACXA1RIKTk7S9pDmX8=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>+lXMCEwIN/7+eMpBrq87kQppxu3jJBTwztGTfXNaPUTx+A6uqRwug5oHBbSpYXKNDNCBzVm/0VxB3bo4FJx+ZQ==</P><Q>yasOGaJaE9xlF9T2xRuKeG9ZxCiyjhYaYB/mbtL+SIbtkRLi/AxaU4g2Il/UxhxhSXArKxIzV28zktispPJx1Q==</Q><DP>ueRgQIEFUV+fY979a1RgrVHIPpqEI1URhOMH3Q59oiXCcOumM5njyIHmWQxRAzXnG+7xlKXi1PrnRll0L4oOKQ==</DP><DQ>dfEMNgG1HJhwpxdtmqkYuoakwQvsIRzcIAuIAJh1DoWaupWJGk8/JEstHb1d+t7uJrzrAi2KyT/HscH2diE0YQ==</DQ><InverseQ>YoYF9PF6FiC0YngVeaC/eqt/ea8wMYNN3YO1LuzWpcy2exPRj2U0ZbWMvHXMUb4ea2qmhZGx1QlK4ULAuWKpXQ==</InverseQ><D>g1WAWI4pEK9TA7CA2Yyy/2FzzNiu0uQCuE2TZYRNiomo96KQXpxwqAzZLw+VDXfJMypwDMAVZe/SqzSJnFEtZxjdxaEo3VLcZ1mnbIL0vS7D6iFeYutF9kF231165qGd3k2tgymNMMpY7oYKjS11Y6JqWDU0WE5hjS2X35iG6mE=</D></RSAKeyValue>")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('rsa1.der',  $rsa1.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey())
& 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe' rsa -check -inform DER -in rsa1.der
```

Here is the output from the openssl command:

```
RSA key error: n does not equal p q
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```